# how to create a new column where the rows are determined by the previous row (calculation)?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

### I have this table and I want to calculate inflation for every month in every city

I tried the lag and lead functions but the CPI was overlapping onto the next city for ex :  Malmo's shifted CPI was Stockholm's 05-01-2005 CPI

| CPI | Date | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | 2005-01-01 | Stockholm |
| 113.5 | 2005-02-01 | Stockholm |
| 115 | 2005-03-01 | Stockholm |
| 115.6 | 2005-04-01 | Stockholm |
| 115.8 | 2005-05-01 | Stockholm |
| 106 | 2005-01-01 | Malmo |
| 107.5 | 2005--02-01 | Malmo |
| 110 | 2005-03-01 | Malmo |
| 113 | 2005-04-01 | Malmo |
| 117 | 2005-05-01 | Malmo |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `group_by` to avoid this issue.

```r
# Read in data
inflation  <- read.table(text = "CPI    Date    City
112 2005-01-01  Stockholm
113.5   2005-02-01  Stockholm
115 2005-03-01  Stockholm
115.6   2005-04-01  Stockholm
115.8   2005-05-01  Stockholm
106 2005-01-01  Malmo
107.5   2005--02-01 Malmo
110 2005-03-01  Malmo
113 2005-04-01  Malmo
117 2005-05-01  Malmo", h = T)

# Perform calculation
library(dplyr)

inflation  |>
    group_by(City)  |>
    mutate(
        cpi_change = lead(CPI) - CPI,
        cpi_change_percent = cpi_change / CPI * 100
    )
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# # Groups:   City [2]
#      CPI Date        City      cpi_change cpi_change_percent
#    <dbl> <chr>       <chr>          <dbl>              <dbl>
#  1  112  2005-01-01  Stockholm      1.5                1.34
#  2  114. 2005-02-01  Stockholm      1.5                1.32
#  3  115  2005-03-01  Stockholm      0.600              0.522
#  4  116. 2005-04-01  Stockholm      0.200              0.173
#  5  116. 2005-05-01  Stockholm     NA                 NA
#  6  106  2005-01-01  Malmo          1.5                1.42
#  7  108. 2005--02-01 Malmo          2.5                2.33
#  8  110  2005-03-01  Malmo          3                  2.73
#  9  113  2005-04-01  Malmo          4                  3.54
# 10  117  2005-05-01  Malmo         NA                 NA
```

You will get NAs for the last month as we do not know the rate in the following year. Alternatively you can do it with `lag` instead of `lead` if you want to work out change from previous, but then you'll get NAs for the first month.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve your problem:

Using `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, CPI_change_perc := (CPI/shift(CPI) - 1) * 100, by=City]

      CPI        Date      City CPI_change_perc
 1: 112.0  2005-01-01 Stockholm              NA
 2: 113.5  2005-02-01 Stockholm       1.3392857
 3: 115.0  2005-03-01 Stockholm       1.3215859
 4: 115.6  2005-04-01 Stockholm       0.5217391
 5: 115.8  2005-05-01 Stockholm       0.1730104
 6: 106.0  2005-01-01     Malmo              NA
 7: 107.5 2005--02-01     Malmo       1.4150943
 8: 110.0  2005-03-01     Malmo       2.3255814
 9: 113.0  2005-04-01     Malmo       2.7272727
10: 117.0  2005-05-01     Malmo       3.5398230
```

Using `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  group_by(City) |> 
  mutate(CPI_change_perc = (CPI/shift(CPI) - 1) * 100)

# A tibble: 10 × 4
# Groups:   City [2]
     CPI Date        City      CPI_change_perc
   <dbl> <chr>       <chr>               <dbl>
 1  112  2005-01-01  Stockholm          NA    
 2  114. 2005-02-01  Stockholm           1.34 
 3  115  2005-03-01  Stockholm           1.32 
 4  116. 2005-04-01  Stockholm           0.522
 5  116. 2005-05-01  Stockholm           0.173
 6  106  2005-01-01  Malmo              NA    
 7  108. 2005--02-01 Malmo               1.42 
 8  110  2005-03-01  Malmo               2.33 
 9  113  2005-04-01  Malmo               2.73 
10  117  2005-05-01  Malmo               3.54
```

##### data

```
df = structure(list(CPI = c(112, 113.5, 115, 115.6, 115.8, 106, 107.5, 
                            110, 113, 117), Date = c("2005-01-01", "2005-02-01", "2005-03-01", 
                                                     "2005-04-01", "2005-05-01", "2005-01-01", "2005--02-01", "2005-03-01", 
                                                     "2005-04-01", "2005-05-01"), City = c("Stockholm", "Stockholm", 
                                                                                           "Stockholm", "Stockholm", "Stockholm", "Malmo", "Malmo", "Malmo", 
                                                                                           "Malmo", "Malmo")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```